# CSS problems :(

Tags: css, image, background

Hey there:) I have been trying to make some nice hover effects for our site. But, when the page loads, it does not load the CSS - background images, and we get some weird flicking effect. I have tried almost everything i think. And we just can't get it to work. I'll link the HTML and the CSS for the problems.

This is the HTML, and the div that contains the CSS. This div is in a main content div and a content div.

```
<div class="produkt_links">
    <div id="produkt_7"><a href="produkt_1.html"></a></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.produkt_links #produkt_7 a {
display: block;
width: 300px;
height: 290px;
background-image:url(../../images/mainpage%20links/arch_low.png);   
}

.produkt_links #produkt_7 a:hover {
background-image:url(../../images/mainpage%20links/arch_low_hover.png); 
}
```

PS. I have tried with sprites. Does not work. Tried in Safari, Chrome and firefox...

Cheers MM.

Comment: Does the rest of the CSS work?

Comment: you are using relative paths, are they correct for the path of where the css file is, have you tried using an absolute url?

Comment: I recommend to use a proper title for your question. Since you tagged it with `css`, we already know that you have a CSS problem.

Comment: The title of the question should briefly describe what the problem is, and the body of the question should describe what you are aiming at, what you have tried, and how the results differ from the expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct the paths for (public) resources used

`background-image:url(../../images/mainpage%20links/arch_low.png);`

---

If the root folder is `public_html`, such that -

```
public_html
 > images
   > mainpage links
     > arch_low.png
```

then use this -

`background-image:url("images/mainpage%20links/arch_low.png");`

Comment: Don't really understand that. I just linked directly to the images - main content folder in the website's folder using url browser in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't written much of the other code,
but I suggest you first try applying something which isn't an image in the css. For example:

```
.produkt_links #produkt_7 a {
display: block;
width: 300px;
height: 290px;
color: blue;   
}

.produkt_links #produkt_7 a:hover {
    color:red; 
}
```

If this doesn't work, check that the CSS file is linked correctly to the HTML file.

Otherwise, check if the path of the image is correct on the server.